# how to fix Main method?

Tags: java, eclipse, main-method

how to fix this problem: Main method not found in class jamel.Jamel, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSTqd.jpg)

Comment: I'm not a programmer and this source code is ready
How do I fix this error?

Comment: Please do not rate negative

Comment: Please share the source code of jamel.Jamel class. Your screenshot is showing a different class.

Comment: if this method - public static void main(String[] args) is not present in your class. You should ask the developer who created this class. Because it depends on the requirements.

Comment: @Sujay Mohan thank you. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The main method is just a method that java calls that actually *does stuff* in your program. If you don't create this method then what is your program for? You'll just have a bunch of classes that you don't use.

Answer (score 0):

If Jamel is your main class where your application starts from scratch then you need

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

this is the entrance of your application to start with.
from here on-words in your main method you should start calling other object. 
but from the screenshot I assume that that is not your want. My guess may be wrong. but figure out what is your starting class and does it have a main method and main method calling right object to start your application.